# Trouble chaining proxies

Tags: proxy, ip

I'm having trouble chaining proxies. I opened terminal, then run this:

```
nano /etc/proxychains.conf
```

I add the list like this

```
[ProxyList]
# add proxy here ...
# meanwile
# defaults set to "tor"
socks4 127.0.0.1 9050
socks5 59.21.114.99 5577
```

I open a new tab, run:

```
proxychains firefox
```

all i get is this

```
ProxyChains-3.1 (http://proxychains.sf.net)
```

Firefox opens but when i google my ip address it is not what it says in the list

Please help

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you using tor browser bundle since it automatically configures proxy settings for you...So above you should specify the application name and local address ..and socks5 uses 127.0.0.1 9050